# Wireless speed between two 802.11n devices is 54Mbps, why?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I'm testing with LAN Speed Test (Lite) and a similar Android app.
I have a DSL-2750U router, Lenovo T530, Nexus 7 (2012 model), and a Buffalo LinkStation Duo NAS: All Wireless N devices.
But my Link speed is around 54Mbps; which is verified by LAN Speed Test. 
Why would this be the case? For reference, my router's advanced config page is below:

[image]

Any ideas why and what to do about this?

Answer (score 3):

Your wifi mode is set to 802.11ng - it will support both 11n and older 11g clients. You can force 11n-only using the "Support 802.11n Client Only" box, or you can set the wifi mode accordingly.

If either your NAS or your other device will not connect once the router is set to serve 11n only, it's likely that the device cannot (or is configured not to) connect to an 11n AP. You can also check your negotiated speed in Windows via the Network and Sharing Center.

You may also get more bandwidth by switching to the 5GHz frequency band - depending on your area, the 2.4GHz band may be congested, but be aware that you may lose some range by switching to 5GHz.

Comment: I've tried N Only but didn't see an improvement. All devices connected suggesting they were compatible.

On going 5GHz, unfortunately the router only has the 2.4GHz mode though it's a drop down.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're either using WPA2 (AES-CCMP) security or none at all.

Original WPA (TKIP) and WEP are not fast enough for 802.11n rates, so devices are required to join in legacy modes (a/b/g) if security is required but WPA2/AES-CCMP is not an option.

Comment: Was using WPA not WPA2. Changing didn't seem to help either :(

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the radio spectrum in your area is simply so congested that you cannot get more than 54 mbps.

And, the maximum speeds advertised with wireless networks are theoretical maximum speeds. That is, the speeds can be reached in an isolated area without any interference to the radio spectrum, and the wireless stations are close to each other.

Comment: Possible, though I doubt it. I'm in a very less developed area that WiFi's are probably in 1 out of 20 homes :)

Answer (score -1):

its a link speed between your router and your device i.e 54mbps not the INTERNET speed from www.speedtest.net. Your device wifi LINK SPEED is limited to 54mbps. So upgrade your ethernet adapter inside your laptop. you will see the change thenafter.
In System Tray (near the clock) locate either Wired or Wireless icon.
Right mouse click on the above icon
Choose "Open Network and Sharing Center"
Look for "Connections" under "View your Active Networks"
Click on the connection, Wired or Wireless status will come up.
Read the line marked "Speed". It will never fluctuate.

I believe that is what you are talking about

Comment: Not at all what I'm talking about

Comment: That explains the behavior, but doesn't give the reason why, which is what was being asked.